# What is the => for in the mapping function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm very new to actual programming not as much blockchain. I know a little Java and am trying to learn solidity I am reading through the [Intro to smart contracts turotial](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#subcurrency-example) and on the 7th line (see below) they declare a variable using mapping but I don't understand how the => comes into play.

```
mapping (address => uint) public balances;
```

Comment: I read that piece code as 'mapping from address to uint'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mapping is similar to Dictionary in Java where you specify key and value pair like

> `var mydictionary = new Dictionary(key,value);`

while in solidity you use the same with => ; where Key = address and uint as value.

Comment: I see I was just confused as to why it is a => as supposed to a =. But your saying this is nothing math related, its just built into solidity that way?

Comment: yup...its more of syntax definition in solidity.

Comment: It is an arrow! It indicates the direction of your mapping. That's all :)

Answer (score 3):

In an array with key value pair; you can refer to a value using the corresponding key.

i.e. `array[key]` will return the `value` stored.

In solidity mapping, can be think of as an array and here in solidity syntax `mapping (address => uint) public balances;`  means that balances has set of `uint` data type values that are mapped by `address` data type.

Basically you can get a corresponding `uint` value for a given address from `balances`. To get a corresponding value here you need to call `balances[address]` and that will return the `uint` value.

You can find a detailed explanation in the [solidity docs here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings).

> Mapping types are declared as `mapping(_KeyType => _ValueType)`. Here
>   `_KeyType` can be almost any type except for a mapping, a dynamically sized array, a contract, an enum and a struct. `_ValueType` can actually
>   be any type, including mappings.
>
> Mappings can be seen as hash tables which are virtually initialized
>   such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose
>   byte-representation is all zeros: a type’s default value. The
>   similarity ends here, though: The key data is not actually stored in a
>   mapping, only its `keccak256` hash used to look up the value.

And [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/how-does-mapping-in-solidity-work) will also be a good read on how mapping works.

Comment: Concise explanation.